# Why doesn't JsArrayString implement iterable?

Tags: javascript, json, gwt, overlay, jsni

Quick question here -- I just used JsArrayString for the first time, and was surprised that this didn't work:

```
JsArrayString object = ...;
for (String s : object)
```

So I just wrote a C-style for loop:

```
JsArrayString object = ...;
for (int i=0; i<object.length(); i++) {
    s = object.get(i)
    ...
```

Not a big deal, but seems like it would have been simple for the GWT team to have JSArrayString implement iterable, so I wanted to check and make sure I wasn't missing something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect it's a matter of code bloat and for that matter code size. If they make `JsArray` implement `Iterable`, it might open the door for other additions that wouldn't always be useful.  `JsArray`s are meant to be absolutely as simple and barebones as possible.

Additionally, you could write your own `JsIterable` class that does this if you want this behavior, as you said it should be pretty trivial to implement.

The [Lightweight Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/LightweightCollections) design doc addresses some of the issues around using JRE collections and related concepts and discusses which features could be left unsupported to ensure absolute minimum code size, including:

> Until the GWT compiler can optimize it (which it cannot to date), the new collections will not support the Java enhanced 'for' loop syntax that uses Iterable/Iterator. We do believe such optimizations are possible and will be added, however, at which time, these collections will be retrofitted to implement Iterable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it the old-school way :). Check out [the source](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/core/client/JsArrayString.java?r=5779) of it.